# Could not send request Postman

Tags: postman

I have this message when I try to use postman:

[image]

I have this in settings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens when you ```ping apirestfulescuelait.dev``` ?

Comment: i run 'ping apirestfulescuelait.dev' 
and i get:
tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud
tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud
tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud
tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud
estadisticas de ping para 192.168.10.11:
        Paquetes enviados= 4, recibidos=0, perdidos=4,

Comment: That means the server cannot be reached at all, so it's not a Postman, but a network issue.